# Tornado: How to log response for all API requests

Tags: python, tornado

I am working on Tornado web server. I want to implement function log request and response for each request. In tornado, I can get whole data of request content but cannot get response body. I have tried using middleware, but middleware doesn't return response also. How can I achieve this purpose.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you `"cannot get response body"`? If you're using `self.write` to send the response, just log it. Or maybe update your question with some example code of your problem.

Comment: @xyres Yes. I knew that. But that doesn't general. I want a general solution (as other web framework), I just write a middleware, and then get response from that.

Comment: same lile ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562718/how-to-log-http-response-in-tornado```